# Как правильно закрепить нижний бар на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно закрепить блок с инпутом в нижней части экрана.
Пока сделал просто через position fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-voice-7re8i

Однако проблема в том, что если скроллить страницу с телефрна, то порой этот закрепленный блок смещается вверх. То есть он не всегда находится на своем месте.

Comment: https://webformyself.com/kak-sozdat-lipkij-futer-s-pomoshhyu-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать `display: flex` с input, это не совсем корректно.
И оберните всё в контейнер, которому уже можете задать `position: fixed и bottom: 0`
Дополнительно дайте:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```